# Batch Script for moving files to the same name folder

Tags: batch

I have the file names like,

- DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2_10.txt
- DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2_11.txt
- L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)_10.txt
- L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)_11.txt

likewise the folder name should be

- DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2
- L-Shaped_Single_Hole_(Elliptical)

Please tell me how can i move the files into the same name folder using batch script file.

Comment: Do your folder names require being without the underscore and numerals? Your example seems to imply this.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask].

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Edited the code and set a variable for the path after the clarification comment:

In order to strip the last three characters from the file name (extension excluded) and use it for the directory creation, then moving the current file inside, use this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath=X:\Insert\Your\Path\Here
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.*) do (
  set "foldername=%%~nf"
  md "!foldername:~0,-3!" >nul 2>&1
  move "%%f" "!foldername:~0,-3!"
)
```

`"foldername=%%~nf"` gets the filename;
`"!foldername:~0,-3!"` strips the last three characters from `foldername`

---

### Old answer and code for reference:

To move the files into a directory that will be created and will carry the same name as the file, without the extension.

If so, then your batch script would look like this:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*) do (
  md "%%~nf"
  move "%%f" "%%~nf"
) >nul 2>&1
```

Comment: No,i have two files like,

DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2_10.txt
DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2_11.txt


Here i want to cerate the folder name like

DC_GEN_FUR_4_Point_Chair_type_2 (without _10 and _11)

and put the both files to the above named folder.Please advice.

Comment: Very well. I have edited the code.

Comment: My hints to improve your answer: **1**. get folder names using [substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) and **2**. move `>nul 2>&1` only to `md` command or omit it at all using `if not exist "…\" md "…"`

Comment: @JosefZ Good ideas, I am still newbie to batch scripting; added first suggested method for **2.**

Comment: I am very new to batch file making.If you give the full script file for move files,it would be very helpful to me.

Comment: Use the script in my comment. You only have to change the `X:\Insert\Your\Path\Here` to the actual path of the files.

Comment: @ManojKumar provided script should work (but correct a minor mistake: `>nul 2>&1` should tail only to `md` command not to `move` one). Please read and **follow** my and [DavidPostill's comments](http://superuser.com/questions/1138283/batch-script-for-moving-files-to-the-same-name-folder#comment1633790_1138283) to your OQ.

Comment: @JosefZ Thank you for catching it. I was editing on mobile via TeamViewer (don't ask why :) ).

Comment: @fragamemnon you are welcome :)

Comment: @ManojKumar, do all of the filenames end with an underscore and two digits (e.g., nothing over 99, and single digit names have a leading zero, like _01)?  If not, you will need something more sophisticated, or will need to do some manual cleanup or multiple passes with formula adjustments.  There is some hidden complexity to your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set folderpath="C:\Desktop\original"
for %%f in (%folderpath%\*.*) do (
  set "foldername=%%~nf"
  md "!foldername:~0,-3!"
  move  "%%f"  "C:\!foldername:~0,-3!"
)
```

I used **"C:\Desktop\original"** folder where all the files saved which have to move to another folder.
The Statement md ***"!foldername:~0,-3!"*** make a folder of the same name but remove the last three characters. Move command move the folder to the desired location.